# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mu (n) z^n}{1-z^n} = z$

Tags: power-series, analytic-number-theory

Where $\mu$ is the mobius function and $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|z| < 1$. I feel like I have to use the mobius inversion formula for absolutely converging series, setting $F(n) =  \frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$ and $f(n) = z$, but I don't get anywhere. The denominator is the real bugger here.

Comment: What is $\mu(m/0)$? What is $\mu(m/n)$ for the integers $n$ that don't divide $m$?

Comment: Fixed it, thank you

Comment: Hint: $1/(1-z^n) = 1+z^n+z^{2n}+z^{3n}+\cdots$.

Comment: Oh my god. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$ \frac{z^n}{1-z^n}=z^n+z^{2n}+z^{3n}+\ldots $$
we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n) z^n}{1-z^n}=\sum_{m\geq 1} z^m\sum_{d\mid m}\mu(d) $$
and $\sum_{d\mid m}\mu(d)$ always equals zero unless $m=1$.